# ng-include not working on iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, phonegap

Please help me on this issue, The below code is working fine on Android but not working on iOS. Its returning the error

> **XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/16B00380-9909-4D99-B4CA-B02DA895431B/Pilot%20Forge.app/www/templates/Menu.html.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var Appclaim = angular.module("app_forge", []);
        Appclaim.controller("claimController", function ($scope) {                
            $scope.MenuTemplate = {
                Name: "Menu.html",
                Url: "templates/Menu.html"
            }
        });
    </script>
    <form name="form" ng-app="app_forge" ng-controller="claimController">
        <div>{{MenuTemplate.Name}}</div>
        <div ng-include="MenuTemplate.Url"></div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have two form open tags an no form close tags. This may be a typo.

Comment: Just change the url to http://localhost instead of localhost. If you open the html file from local, you should create a local server to serve that html file

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this today - adding this to the config.xml under the ios platform section fixed it for me.

```
<preference name="scheme" value="app" />
<preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
```

That and making sure you have the newest version of the iOS platform added / and that you are using WKWebView instead of the UIWebView.

Here's a GitHub issue that helped to find the answer:

[Cordova not allowing https cross origin requests.](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/1082)

And here's a link to the article on Cordova's site:

[UPDATED: How to handle the 'Deprecated API Usage - UIWebView' warning while uploading to the App Store](https://cordova.apache.org/howto/2020/07/18/uiwebview-warning.html)

I guess iOS treats all file:// protocols as cross origin now. (iOS is proving to be a real pain to develop for.)